# Can't pull metadata for a term in my theme's function.php

Tags: plugins, terms

I have a strange issue where I've attached custom metadata to a Woocommerce product category using the KC Settings plugin and for some reason, I can access the data just fine in a separate plugin that I wrote as well as Debug Bar's console but not in my functions.php

Here's what the working code (in its most basic form) in the console and plugin looks like:

```
global $woocommerce;
echo (float) get_metadata( 'term', 14, 'latitude', true );
```

Unfortunately, it just returns a '0' instead of the actual value when executed from functions.php. I typecast it since I need it to return a number but PHP interprets the value of the metadata as a string.

Why will this work in a plugin as well as in the console, but not in the functions.php?

EDIT: using `get_metadata()` on a post works just fine.  Why is it the terms object that causing the issue?

EDIT 2: Even more confusing is the fact that I've written out a wpdb query to manually pull it and I just get a white page when I try to add an item to the cart.  This query works perfectly in the console however.

`$wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->wp_termmeta WHERE term_id = 14 AND meta_key = 'latitude'" );`

Comment: what action is this code hooked to?

Comment: It's hooked to woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` is a filter that is run in the `add_to_cart_action` method of the `WC_Form_Handler` class.

This method is attached to the `init` hook.

`add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_to_cart_action' ) );`

Your taxonomy is quite probably also registered at the `init` hook.  The WooCommerce action has no priority set, so the default would be 10.  I would try to register your taxonomy with a higher priority (lower number), so that the taxonomy is definitely registered *before* the `add_to_cart_action` is run. (Just a guess, and not verified)

Comment: How would I go about registering the taxonomy with a higher priority? Would I do that within the current filter or would that be elsewhere?  It's a woocommerce product category that I'm looking to get the meta from.

Comment: I also see that you might be onto something given this issue on Github: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/pull/2691

Comment: It looks like it was pulled in to core 8 months ago? What version of WC are you using, because my code has the taxonomies registered with a priority of 5 (though I am using 2.1-bleeding). Browsing github, I'd guess that the issue was resolved in 2.0.3ish.

Comment: I'm using the latest package from Wordpress' plugins manager (2.0.19) which is also the latest version available for download on the website.

Comment: FYI, I found the line where product_cat is registered: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-post-types.php#L57 but there is no priority set.  Is the priority set in the action or in the register_taxonomy line?

Comment: Priority is on the `add_action`. Looks like it has a priority of 5 which should be coming before the `add_to_cart_action` function, so I'm confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: What's even more confusing is why the $wpdb query won't work either.

Comment: Have you tried installing a clean version of the lastest WooCommerce?

Comment: It would be a highly intensive process to start over.  I tried uninstalling and re-installing woocommerce but it didn't work